Ad Inserter Pro - Adsense ad not serving
I'm using Ad Inserter Pro to insert Adsense code to my page. I have problem with specific ad. According Ad Inserter documentation:

Blank AdSense ad block means that the code is inserted properly and running, only the ad code doesn’t display anything – Google AdSense is not serving ads.

I have like 4 ads, that from Adsense that are displaying just fine. Only one is not serving. I have no idea why. Can it be because there is no real traffic? The web is still staging so no real users are visiting it.
The page is approved by Google ads, AdSense account is fully approved, no ban, AdSense publisher ID and slot ID is correct. No errors in code.
I'm running out of ideas, it's not Ad inserter problem - I tried to insert the code in post with same result.
The code Im using


<script async src="pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/…" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-format="autorelaxed" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxx" data-ad-slot="xxxxx"></ins> <script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script> 



Thanks in advance

The code generated by Adsense:


